# receiving FCM registration token late in ios

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-fcm

I am using react-native-fcm package to get FCM token.

```
FCM.getFCMToken()
```

When i install release/debug version of react native app on iPhone device, I am receiving FCM token after some time and not at app initialization(start up).

My package.json uses

```
"react": "16.0.0",
"react-native": "0.50.4",
"react-native-fcm": "git+https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm.git#sdk-26",
"react-native-firebase": "3.3.1",
```

Comment: If you are just starting out with integrating fcm in your app I would suggest using https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase

Comment: No, I am done with integration and it is working fine for android. But for ios, when I build the app, if I call FCM.getToken() before "FCM registration token: "is printed in the Xcode console, I am not able to get FCM token